# How can I add Chinese character support to Emerald?

Tags: arch-linux, compiz, window-decorations

I'm running Arch Linux, using the Emerald window decorator. Emerald crashes in the following situations:

- A window with at least one Chinese character in the title is opened.
- An open window's title changes to something with at least one Chinese character

When it crashes, it gives the following `stderr`:

```
emerald: cairo-scaled-font.c:459: _cairo_scaled_glyph_page_destroy: Assertion `!scaled_font->cache_frozen' failed.
```

Which is immediately followed with what seems to be a standard C++ error on `stdout`:

```
Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

A few extra notes:

- I initially thought this was some problem with CJK encoding. However, it doesn't seem to happen when I load a page with Korean or Japanese in the title. Only Chinese. Of course, it's still entirely possible that some CJK package will fix my problems.
- Emerald version: 0.8.8
- Compiz version: 0.8.9
- Desktop Environment: Mate Desktop 1.6.1
- Linux Kernel: 3.12.1
- Nvidia driver version: 331.20

Comment: That's bug.  Report it.  Assertions in production code imply a problem spot. It may be something in the configuration of the cairo stack, so start by reporting it downstream, to Arch, first.

Comment: @goldilocks Sounds good. I'll report it on the AUR.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps much, but I saw this same error in Lubuntu.  Lxterminal and several other apps would crash.  However, xterm ran, and when I tried to launch lxterminal from xterm, I saw that error message.

There is a workaround in Lubuntu.  In Preferences->Customize Look and Feel, under the Widgets tab (the default), change "Lubuntu-default" to anything else, such as "Mist".